# jQuery is deleting elements

Tags: jquery, html-table

I've got a problem with jQuery. I need to copy some code, to append is somewhere else.

The source I like to take a copy from is like this:

```
<div id="copyCode" style="display: none">
    <div class="ofPagedataTable">
        <tr class="page copy">
            <td class="id"><input type="text" /></td>
            <td class="sprache"><input type="text" /></td>
            <td class="description"><input type="text" /></td>
            <td class="title"><input type="text" /></td>
            <td class="keywords"><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery I'm using is like this:

```
$('.addPageToPagedata').click(function(){
    html = $("#copyCode").children(".ofPagedataTable").html();
    target = $('.pagedata tbody').children(':last');    
    $(html).appendTo(target);
    });
```

It's kind of working, but jQuery is taking away the `<tr>` and `<td>` Elements and it is appending just:

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

I'dont know what to do. It would be nice if someone can give me a suggestion how to solve this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think jQuery remove anything. You html is not valid. You can't put `td` and `tr` here. Your browser just remove this elements by itself.

Comment: Thank you, that was kind of dump from me.

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping the `tr` in `<table>` tags, to make the html valid.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, because you have invalid markup - `tr` can only be inside a `table` tag. When browser sees your invalid markup, it tries to automatically fix it, so it simply removes all your `tr` and `td` elements.

Answer (score 1):

jquery is working based on the tag tbody, but you do not have a table here. Without a table, tr s and td s do not make any sense, as basically you are trying to operate on columns and rows, when they don't even exist. Hence, wrap them in a table. Only then will this work .